# JKCalendar library does not called tableview delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I used JKCalendar calendar library.

In that library, I use `JKCalendarTableView` and set the delegate.

But the `TableView` delegate method `didSelectRowAt` method not called.

Code :

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: reservationView.frame.size.width, height: reservationView.frame.size.height)
calendarTableView = JKCalendarTableView(frame: frame)
calendarTableView.addShadow(cornerRadius: 6, opacity: 0.5, radius: 4, offset: (x: 0, y: 0), color: .lightGray)
calendarTableView.calendar.delegate = self
calendarTableView.calendar.dataSource = self
calendarTableView.delegate = self
calendarTableView.dataSource = self
calendarTableView.tag = TAGS.reservationViewTextFiledTag  + 12
calendarTableView.calendar.focusWeek = selectDay.weekOfMonth - 1
calendarTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
reservationView.addSubview(calendarTableView)
self.calendarTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: where didSelectRowAt  ??

Comment: did you found the solution?